# Chat shows user as owner after they were removed

Tags: bug, chat

A user removed themselves as owner yet their name is still italicized. Is this a bug? It appears the only way to get it removed is for me to logout and log back in.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can also just refresh the page. Chat doesn't (currently) automatically refresh the information it uses to make display decisions about usernames, since it's only cosmetic.